When did iOS remove the ability to set the alarm clock to play a Music playlist?
I am virtually certain that in early iOS products -- for example, on my old 5th-generation iPod Touch, which was contemporary with the iPhone 5, and which shipped with iOS 6 -- one could set the stock Alarm Clock to use a playlist (from the Music app) instead of an alarm. That feature seems to no longer exist; while it is still possible to play an individual song as an alarm, one can no longer choose to play an entire playlist.
When exactly did this feature go away? That is, in what version of iOS was this feature removed?
PS: And just to forestall the obvious: I am aware of the work-around using the Shortcuts app. It seems unnecessarily complicated, and in any case that doesn't answer my question.

I removed the speculation part of the question. Nevertheless, the question kind of lacks the practical problem to be solved. What does it help to know that the functionality was removed with iOS 42?

@nohillside are questions about the history of Apple products off-topic? I apologize if that's the case, I wasn't aware.

They are at least at the border ... :- From What topoics can I ask about here: "If you have a question about a practical problem you are trying to solve as a user of [Apple Products", that's why I asked about the practical problem to be solved :-)

I mean the practical problem is kind of obvious -- I would like to be able to use the stock Alarm app to play music from a playlist in Apple Music -- but I am fairly certain that cannot be done, so I'm not sure there's much point in asking it.

That‘s not what you are asking though, but for which you already have an answer.
